# PHP script timeout on IIS after 15 minutes

Tags: php, iis, timeout, cgi, internal-server-error

Ok, so I wrote a PHP script that's set to scrape data from an HTML table (data being pulled from an awful bit of proprietary data collection software) and throw it into a database after it's finished scraping.. The table will sometimes have around 100,000 or more records to it, so it'll take a fair amount of time to accomplish this, despite the server's healthy specs. The script works just fine with a small data set, but when I try to test it with a more realistic, large data set, the script will run for 15 minutes and then return a 500 error to the browser without any error being logged. I removed the time limit on both PHP AND CGI (set cgi to 3hrs instead of 15mins), restarted the servers and all associated services, but it's STILL timing out after 15 minutes exactly... I have no idea what I'm missing here, does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check phpinfo() to see what the max_execution_time is? You're only assuming that you successfully changed the timeout value.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that as well, sorry. It's set at 0, currently

Comment: Still didn't work through the browser, but I bypassed the browser and ran the script through the CLI and that worked so I assume the issue lies in IIS somewhere..

Comment: could be, yeah. php won't be able to override iis timeouts.